# PHP Warning that I cant get rid of .. "missing mcrypt.so" .. but phpinfo() shows it

Tags: php

I have this error showing up in iTerm again..

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so
Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

It's just a warning, so I can still work.  But I want to get rid of it.

Thing is, I have been down this road before.  I have installed mcrypt before when this problem came up previously (with homebrew, I think .. but I was a bit more clueless then than I am now, I was just following some sites.  At any rate, the error had disappeared for a few months).

Mcrypt shows in my phpinfo() and the mcrypt.so file is there in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so

Any ideas what the problem is?  Can anyone give me a hand troubleshooting this?

(I realize that this question has already been asked, but the answer is usually just "You are missing the extension", or "comment out the line in php.ini".  I would like to understand what is going on and solve the problem without commenting out mcrypt, as that always seems to raise new additional issues.  Specifically, Laravel needs it.)

Comment: It's a longshot, but remember there are two php.ini files: one for command line and one for the web/apache part. Maybe this helps

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly Thanks.  But the fact that it is looking for mcrypt should mean that it is in the .ini right (and it is).  The problem is that it just doesn't seem to "see" the .so file, or whatever that "image not found" error is.  I don't want to comment it out because I can't run Laravel without Mcrypt.  Thanks for the reminder though.  Have a point.